# Problem with the table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am writing a work about logarithms and in the table of contents I am confronted with this problem:

[image: problem]

There is no space between the number of the sub sub-subsection and the title:

2.3.10.1 Função Exponencial

2.3.10.2 Gráfico da função exponencial

2.3.10.3 Função inversa

2.3.10.4 Função Logarítmica

2.3.10.5 Gráfico da função logarítmica

How can I get the correct spaces?

Comment: Which class are you using? If I use `book` everything is ok with the spacing of subsubsections in the TOC. A minimal working example is never wrong to show the undesired behaviour...

Comment: @Ruben But the question is about subsubsubsections which don't exist in `book`... (or `article` or `report`...)

Comment: @Henfe This is why all questions need to include a Minimal Working Example i.e. the code of a complete small document demonstrating the issue. As it is, you expect potential helpers to somehow divine the essential contents of your document from nothing but an image. While the abilities of members of this site are not to be sneezed at, they do not yet extend to an entirely reliable capacity for mind reading...

Comment: Please try the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package.